# Modificar URL en codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

buenas, estoy comenzando a utilizar php y codeigniter como framework, y quiero saber si es posible modificar la url, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente controlador user y dentro un metodo edit para editar los datos de un usuario la url quedaría de esta forma: http://localhost/sis/user/edit/2, quiero saber si es posible ocultar el parámetro que le paso al método de mi controlador

Comment: hola, si es posible ocultar **carpeta/controllador/metodo** esto lo haces en **applications/config/routes.php** tienes que agregar `$route['nombre-bonito/(:num)'] = 'user/edit/$1';` [userguide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routing)

Comment: puedes documentarte un poco ... https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Mod-rewrite

Comment: gracias por las sugerencias las revisare

Comment: tambien ay veces el que el url lo encuentras en el archivo .env

Answer (score 0):

Entendería que tu intención es la siguiente:

Teniendo funcionando la url:

`http://localhost/sis/user/edit/2`

Quieres ocultar su parámetro, con algo como:

`http://localhost/sis/588b5bb2ee3d8e59314a58f7bf405a558587b05f`

Ahí va una solución:

$route[sha1('edit_user/(:num)')] = 'user/edit/$1';

Y en el origen del enlace usas:
`<a href="<?php echo base_url(sha1('edit_user/2')); ?>">EDITAR</a>`

Todo esto asumiendo que has eliminado el /index.php/ de tu url con .htaccess, y que en tu configuración tienes: 
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sis/';